# Is it possible to use Matrix Based security with Google Login plugin?

Tags: jenkins, google-authentication

I'm trying to set up Jenkins security using the Google Login plugin (v1.3).

I'm able to login with Google using accounts within our domain, however I'd ideally like to have me as an admin user with everyone else as more locked-down users.

I'd been hoping to do that using Matrix based security options, but Google Login adds 2 user groups (Anon and authenticated users), but adding my own login (both with and without my domain) doesn't seem to override the authenticated user settings, meaning everyone gets the cut-down version.

Is there any way to get this kind of setup to work? An alternative would be to let me go to a standard username/password page if I don't log in via Google, but I'd need to have a Google redirect me to a page other than the Jenkins home page (which takes me straight back to Google auth)